# java.lang.AbstractMethodError at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure while deploying EAR in JBOSS AS 7

Tags: spring, hibernate, jboss7.x

I got the following error while deploying my EAR in JBOSS AS7:

```
Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'entityManagerFactory' defined in class path resource [META-INF/springDAOContext.xml]: Invocation of init method failed; nested exception is java.lang.AbstractMethodError
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1338)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory$1.run(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:409)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:380)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory$1.getObject(AbstractBeanFactory.java:264)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:222)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:261)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:185)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:164)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeansOfType(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:308)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanFactoryUtils.beansOfTypeIncludingAncestors(BeanFactoryUtils.java:270)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.detectPersistenceExceptionTranslators(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:122)
        at org.springframework.dao.support.PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationInterceptor.java:78)
        at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.<init>(PersistenceExceptionTranslationAdvisor.java:70)
        at org.springframework.dao.annotation.PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.setBeanFactory(PersistenceExceptionTranslationPostProcessor.java:97)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.initializeBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1326)
        at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:473)
        ... 56 more
Caused by: java.lang.AbstractMethodError
        at org.hibernate.ejb.Ejb3Configuration.configure(Ejb3Configuration.java:632)
        at org.hibernate.ejb.HibernatePersistence.createContainerEntityManagerFactory(HibernatePersistence.java:72)
```

I had added spring.jar (2.5.6) as a module in JBOSS 7. I got NoClassDef error for hibernate class after adding spring as module. To fix that, I added dependency for org.hiberernate module in spring module.

I got Abstractmethod error after adding the dependency. I think it occurs due to the version mismatch between hibernate jar in my lib folder and JBOSS module.

Is their any way I can force JBOSS to look my lib directory for hibernate jar instead of modules?

Any help will be highly appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: Did you add org.hibernate as a dependency in the module.xml of your Spring module?

Comment: Yes, I did. I fixed this issue by upgrading spring version to 3.2.2 and hibernate version to 4.0.1. Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This issue occurred due to the version mismatch in jars.

I fixed this issue by upgrading spring version to 3.2.2 and hibernate version to 4.0.1.